# How to use RVM and different versions of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

Hi I am beginner to ruby on rails. I have following this on my machine

```
nilkash@nilkash:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [i686-linux]
nilkash@nilkash:~$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.3
nilkash@nilkash:~$ rvm -v

rvm 1.19.6 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

nilkash@nilkash:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

nilkash@nilkash:~$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p392 (found in /home/nilkash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392)
   (default)
   global
   latest_rails_stable
=> rails3tutorial2ndEd
```

I also install rails version 4.0.0. But I don't know how to use different versions of rails. when i create new project it shows rails version 3.x. I want to upgrade it to version 4. How to check list of all installed rails  and how to use latest one. Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend rbenv instead of rvm, but that is just a personal preference. Normally you should be able to choose different gemsets and have there a specific ruby version. In the past I created always a clean an fresh new gemset for a new project..so first create a gemset, second choose the new gemset, third install the newest rails, fourth use it :-). Should work..

Comment: Managing multiple versions of Rails and gems :http://railsapps.github.io/managing-rails-versions-gems.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I also install rails version 4.0.0. But I don't know how to use different versions of rails. when i create new project it shows rails version 3.x. I want to upgrade it to version 4. How to check list of all installed rails and how to use latest one. Need Help. Thank you.

this is because you're still using the current gemset rails3tutorial2ndEd

You need to create a different gemset:

```
rvm gemset create <new_gemset_name>
```

then use it:

```
rvm gemset use <new_gemset_name>
```

and finally install a new rails version:

```
gem install rails -v <version_number>
```

only after doing these things will you be able to make a new project with a different rails version.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to only do a quick command in different rails version you can do:

```
 $ rails _4.0.1_ new MyRailsApp
```

That way you don't have some gems installed twice as you do when you use gem sets. Bundler should handle the rest so you should only need one gemset.

Answer (score 4):

In your Gemfile, you will see the line `gem 'rails', '3.2.3'` or which version you are using. You can modify it and execute bundle again.

You can execute `gem list --local` on the console to check all versions of your gems installed.

In my opinion, you would better to use rvmrc to define different gemset in the different projects, it reduces chaos. see details: https://rvm.io/workflow/projects

Answer (score 3):

you can create gemset with `rvm gemset create <gemset name>` then switch to it `rvm use <ruby version>@<gemset name>` and install another version of rails in this gemset

Answer (score 0):

You can have a different ruby version for different gems. 
I am going to give an example way to manage for ruby 2.1.10 with rails 4.1 and ruby 2.4.1 with rails 5.1. 
This is a quote from rvm official [website](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) take a look.

> RVM gives you compartmentalized independent ruby setups. This means
>   that ruby, gems and irb are all separate and self-contained - from the
>   system, and from each other.
>
> You may even have separate named gemsets.

I am supposing you had already installed a different version of ruby. To list user `rvm list`. It will list installed ruby and currently which one be using. 
if you have not installed any no problem follow this official rvm [documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

- **Install 2.1.10 with rails 4.1.0**

  `rvm use 2.1.10
  gem install rails -v 4.1.0
  rvm use 2.1.10@rails410 --create
  rvm 2.1.10`

*ready and good to go for ruby 2.1.10 with rails 4.1.0*

- **Install 2.4.1 with rails 5.1.0**

  `rvm use 2.4.1
  gem install rails -v 5.1.0
  rvm use 2.4.1@rails510 --create
  rvm 2.4.1`

*ready and good to go ruby 2.4.1 with rails 5.1.0*

You have set 2 gemsets above. Just `use rvm 2.1.10` for ruby 2.1.10 and rails 4.1 and `rvm 2.4.1` for ruby 2.4.1 and rails 5.1.0.